# InterruptedIOException while using Retrofit2 with rx when retryOn

Tags: android, rx-java, okhttp, rx-android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2 with rx-android

I have quite complex retry logic, **which partially works**. I cut off irrelevant code to simplify it. Here it is:

```
public class RetryWithDelay implements Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>, Constants {

@Override
public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
    return attempts.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
            int statusCode = 500;
            if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;
                statusCode = httpException.code();
            }

            boolean shouldRetry = shouldRetry();

            if (shouldRetry && statusCode == 401 && requiresAuthorization) {
                LoginProvider provider = AppUtils.getExternalProvider(context);
                switch (provider) {
                    case GOOGLE:
                        return reauthorizeGoogleProvider();
                    case FACEBOOK:
                        return reauthorizeFacebookProvider();
                    default:
                        return reauthorizeApiProvider();
                }
            } else if (shouldRetry) {
                return Observable.timer(Configuration.REQUEST_RETRY_DELAY_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } else {
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            }
        }
    });

    }
```

I have network call observable which throws 401. Then retry logic is triggered. The call looks like

```
observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .retryWhen(new RetryWithDelay(getActivity()))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyArticles>() {
                    //code removed for simplicity
                });
```

When I get the 401 RetryWithDelay switch triggers one of three methods.
It works fine when the user was login natively in my api, which calls:

```
private Observable<?> reauthorizeApiProvider() {
    return retrofitService.loginWithRefreshToken(data).flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(User user) {
            app.setUserInfo(UserInfo.fromUser(user));
            AppUtils.saveUserData(context, user);
            return Observable.timer(0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
        }
    });
}
```

But for facebook or google ends up with mysterious exception: `java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted`. This is how I do it for google - same way for facebook.

```
private Observable<?> reauthorizeGoogleProvider() {
    return retrofitService.loginWithExternalProvider(LoginProvider.GOOGLE, externalAccessToken).flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(User user) {
            //some irrelevant logic
            return Observable.timer(0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
        }
    });
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the params I pass to retrofit method. This method with the very same params is successfully used while signing in and not a part of retry logic.

Here is full stack trace:

```
    java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:77)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:141)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.finishRequest(HttpTransport.java:52)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$300(HttpEngine.java:92)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:891)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:749)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:268)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.myapp.android.dagger.ApiModule$1.intercept(ApiModule.java:81)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:221)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:116)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:111)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:88)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:231)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:140)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$3$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:307)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$3$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:289)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:254)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(BehaviorSubject.java:160)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.onError(OnSubscribeRedo.java:242)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:239)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:774)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:532)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:521)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:808)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$ThrowObservable$1.call(Observable.java:9600)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$ThrowObservable$1.call(Observable.java:9590)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:231)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:140)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:113)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:88)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-20 09:13:48.718 6041-6041/com.myapp.android W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please advise

EDIT: Investigations shows that it's somehow connected to http method. `loginWithRefreshToken` is `POST` and `loginWithExternalProvider` is `GET`. Works when changed ti POST. But that's stupid. Need real solution.

Comment: Interesting approach. Any reason why you are not using an Interceptor for the 401 ?

Comment: Just felt like doing it this way. Kinda cooler and cleaner to do it in rx.I guess I could try add it to interceptor as a last resort...

Comment: uhm ok, why do you think it is cleaner to do it in rx?

Comment: because in the interceptor I'd have to build the whole request on my own and mantain some shared code like method url, heders and stuff. i don't like it. Funny thing is this logic works under some circumstances, I'll edit the question

Comment: I have similar problem. Im using RxTextView.textChanges with debounce and switchMap (to send new request and ignore the old one) to get query for API call and sometimes (I think, when two or more requests are sent), it just crashing just like yours. Do you have already some solution to this?

Comment: No solution. Gave up on this.

Comment: Usually the InterruptedIOException appears when you unsubscribe from the network request observable before the request has been finished. After unsubscribing your thread will not be assigned to that Observable anymore and can (and will) be used for other stuff, thus OkHttp will throw this exception. Are you sure you're not accidentally unsubscribing from the retry logic?

Comment: I solved this problem,just not start new thread when refresh token.